# Recover MongoDB data without WiredTiger.wt file

Tags: mongodb, recovery, mongodb-3.2, mongodb-3.4, wiredtiger

We have recovered a MongoDB database from filesystem, but the `WiredTiger.wt` file has changed since then (i.e. the collection has been dropped).

So is it possible to read data (documents) from some `.wt` files without having the corresponding `WiredTiger.wt`?

Or create a `WiredTiger.wt` file with our own `.wt` files?

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40891411/recovering-a-missing-wiredtiger-wt).

Comment: Have you tested what happens if you use older WiredTiger.wt file? You can always drop those collections again OR use wt command ( http://source.wiredtiger.com/2.6.0/command_line.html ) to manipulate that WiredTiger.wt file.

Comment: Yes. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you perform the recovery by overwriting some `collection-*.wt` files inside your `dbpath`, then your database is in an unsupported state. Data loss is quite likely in this case.

If you want to restore the database, you would need to restore the `dbpath` as a whole and not as individual files. Please see [MongoDB Backup Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/) for instructions and information on supported backup and restore methods.

The `WiredTiger.wt` file is a crucial metadata file that keeps track of the state of the whole database and all the `*.wt` files. Hence, the content of this file is deployment specific, and not transferrable to other deployments. It is not possible to recreate the content of this file.

If you have a known good backup of the whole `dbpath`, you may be able to restore to a valid state of the database, as long as you restore the `dbpath` as a whole.

Comment: I tried to write a program to read the `*.wt` files but it didn't work. It seems that there's not a simple way to recover them.